# Mongoose connection is not open when I try to run node file on it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to run index.js with node and I have the required code written for the connection to be established, but nothing happens.

I have already installed mongoose(npm i mongoose) and npm init -y. I have node,mongodb installed on my computer and everything, but it just doesn't work.

[New Problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6WOp.png)
[New Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHG6P.png)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("OH NO MONGO CONNECTION ERROR!!!!")
        console.log(err)
    })

const productSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    price : Number,
    season: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"]
    }

});
const farmSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    city: String,
    products: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }]
})

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)
const Farm = mongoose.model("Farm", farmSchema)


// Product.insertMany([
//     {name: "Goddes Melon", price: 4.99, season: "Summer"},
//     {name: "Sugar Baby Watermelon", price: 4.99, season: "Summer"},
//     {name: "Asparagus", price: 3.99, season: "Spring"}
// ])


// const makeFarm = async() => {
//     const farm = new Farm ({name: "Fully Belly Farms", city: Guinda, CA});
//     const melon = await Product.findOne({name : "Godes Mellon" });
//     farm.products.push(melon);
//     await farm.save()
//     console.log(farm)
// }

// makeFarm();

const addProduct = async() => {
    const farm = await Farm.findOne({name: "Full Bally Farms"})
    const watermelon = await Product.findOne({name: "Sugar Baby Watermelon"})
    farm.products.push(watermelon)
    await farm.save();
    console.log(farm)
}

addProduct();
```

Comment: Mongoose is only the code layer. You also need to have a MongoDB instance running. Do you? If not https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo - take a look at the instructions here

Comment: @jnelson yes I have mongod.exe running and mongo.exe.

Comment: Awesome. The connect function should throw an error as a promise rejection. Could you wrap it in a try/catch or catch() and log the error (add it to the question)? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/5.x/docs/connections.html#error-handling

Comment: @jnelson i have added it.

Comment: instead of handleError - use console.error OR console.log and add the error text in the question :-)

Comment: @jnelson this now seems to be working fine for some reason. But could you check another case where it can't seem to find the module and I'll add the picutres in this question post? I already added it

Comment: farm.js is in the Models directory :-). So you should be calling node models/farm.js instead

Comment: @jnelson there's still an error, i updated the post.

Comment: 1. You don't have farm.js in Your location (try to check with: `ls -la`), 2. You have issue in model which You're getting null for parent object which should have `products`

Comment: @num8er i have added the code into the question, please check it out. And farm.js is in  the location, since I checked it this moment. So i don't know what the problem is.

Comment: `products: {type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: "Product", default: [] }`

Comment: `if (!farm.products) farm.products = []; farm.products.push(watermelon);`

Comment: `farm.js` is Models folder (I don't know why You're trying to call it), so if You insist call it like: `node Models/farm.js`

Comment: @num8er stiill the same error. I give up.

Comment: @num8er i'm calling it because I want to see them in my powershell db.products.find(), so I can see if I did the exercise I'm currently learning rightfully.